# What happened in Maztica to make Tabaxi emigrate?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, tabaxi

I am currently playing a Tabaxi Druid, Circle of the Moon. I wanted to flesh out his backstory, so I read up on them in Volo's Guide to Monsters. In a box on page 113, it said:

> In the Forgotten Realms, tabaxi hail from Maztica, a realm
>   located far across the ocean west of the Sword Coast. The
>   tabaxi of Maztica are known for their isolation, and until
>   recently they never ventured from their homeland. The
>   tabaxi say little of why that has changed, though rumors
>   persist of strange happenings in that distant land.

I thought that it would be interesting to have my Tabaxi immigrate from Maztica to Faerun, and then travel to Chult for the current adventure, Tomb of Annihilation. There's only one problem: I don't know why my Tabaxi, along with many others, left Maztica. Are the problems detailed in a published adventure, or does Volo's Guide just leave it up to the player? I want to roleplay my character better, and I think that knowing what happened to my home island will help.

Comment: Are you open to lore answers from previous editions?

Comment: The D&D 5e tag is only describing the system they're using — answers from prior editions are fine and dandy if they're relevant to D&D 5e, and should mention that we should look to those if there's nothing in D&D 5e. The system tag isn't doing anything magical here that removing it would dismiss, just describing the circumstances of the question. Since the asker is playing 5e, we'd be answering with 5e-relevant answers whether there was a tag or not. (But, there is, since it's relevant.)

Answer (score 8):

**Disclaimer**: The following is speculation based on information about other areas that suffered a similar fate.

There is precious little information available about Maztica, especially in this regard. However there is some informed speculating we can do to help you come up with your own story.

During the Spellplague, Maztica was switched with Laerakond (although not in geographically identical spaces). Maztica was sent to Abeir, while Laerakond came from there. (Abeir was a second planet that was once merged with Toril). Maztica returned with the Sundering, and Laerakond also remained.

The kingdom of Unther (a human empire) also switched with Tymanther (part of a Dragonborn empire), which brought Dragonborn to Toril. Unther returned (most of Tymanther switched but some remained) with the Sundering. Unther has been mostly destroyed and overrun by the creatures in Abeir (mostly Genasi I think), and had only recently regained their kingdom before returning to Toril.

Using Unther as an example, we can maybe speculate that Mazticas stay in Abeir led to strange changes in ecology and the political landscape. Especially if Maztica was connected to a new landmass, it could have been ravaged by new diseases, strange beasts, or empires looking for easy conquest. Theres already some record of diseases running wild there after colonists from Faerun attempted to establish cities.

**TL;DR** Maztica was sent to Abeir, and likely had any number of strange developments on that new planet. Now that it's back, perhaps the Tabaxi are fleeing some lurking danger that they could not escape until now.

Comment: Which editions/novels/published material covered this? Was this 4e lore?

Answer (score 2):

Amn happened.

Read in the [Maztica Campaign Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maztica_Campaign_Set) (AD&D 2e) and the wikis on the net on how they enslaved the people and they not only willingly migrated but were shipped as slaves to Chult.

Also very interesting, especially for my shocked Helm Paladin when starting the *Tomb of Annihilation* published adventure, was the kind of massacre this church did over there despite being protector paladins.

Comment: Which edition was that campaign setting linked to?  Multiple? One?

Comment: mpathy, I did a word search on the Maztica 2e Campaign Set yesterday afternoon, and found no reference to tabaxi.  Is there a particular edition's version of Maztica that you refer to that supports your point on the tabaxi leaving Maztica due to Amn's incursions there?  Or was this from one of the Forgotten Realms novels or a CRPG?

Answer (score 0):

In the older editions, there was a trading route from Amn, to Maztica, and most of their trading occurs back and forth there. There's also a colony on Maztica from Amn. Go with that.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! We expect answers to be independent answers to the question. To that end I think you can improve this answer by [edit]ing in a more direct answer to the question as posed. Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!