# What is the current state of Maztica?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms

I am planning to use a custom setting which is a kind of fantasy/Wild West crossover for my new 5e campaign. I'm aware there is actually the New World counterpart in Forgotten Realms called Maztica, but I'm not sure it would be a good idea to use it. Anyways the new setting will be based on Faerun with some American Old West flavor added.

During the Spellplague, Maztica was switched places with Laerakond, then it was returned with the Sundering. Aside from that I have little to no information about what the current state of Maztica is. Most of the information I've found so far is from the pre-plague period.

What does Maztica look like now? Did it survive the Sundering? Is there any official information available about its state in 1496 DR? Are there any active colonization endeavours from Amn, or was it forgotten by the people of Faerun?

Comment: Related question (not a duplicate): [What happened in Maztica to make Tabaxi emigrate?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110407/what-happened-in-maztica-to-make-tabaxi-emigrate)

Answer (score 3):

### I'm afraid there's no official content about that yet...

... but there's an official campaign which has some Lantanese in it ("Steampunk-Atlantis" close to Maztica and also disappeared to Abeir). I spoiled myself accidentally, because I play a gnomish Artificer from Lantan (that lived in Faerun since before the Spellplague) and stumbled upon some campaign info. I don't know any more about that and don't know whether those Lantanese give any interesting info about what happened exactly to their homeland. So I can't tell you any details, because I don't want to spoil myself anymore and don't want to spoil the story for anyone else, because it's a pretty nice campaign.

If you don't mean to play that campaign, maybe have a look into

> Waterdeep: Dragonheist

I don't know if there's anything useful in it... there might be something tho... but again: I don't want to spoil anything for anyone here (me included).

Apart from that: Did you look into the Faerun Fandom?

https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Maztica

https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Lantan

The Fandom-Wiki and that official campaign are the only sources I know of regarding Maztica.  I dug deep for my 383 year old gnome-character, but maybe not deep enough.

My DM/girlfriend (same person) told me that the designers might have something planned for Lantan and Maztica but I don't know if that was just a distraction maneuver to stop me from researching my character's background too much. So present Maztica pretty much seems like a yet to be filled blank spot on the map. Right now you can fill it (as a DM) with your imagination.

You could imagine it as a Wild West steampunk(ish) continent, but if official lore is of value to you, you may want to leave room to get retconned on this by upcoming official stuff.

Comment: "Lantanese in it ("Steampunk-Atlantis" located in Maztica)" - Lantan isn't in Maztica at all. As your two FR wiki links state: "Lantan was an island-nation in the Trackless Sea north of the Chultan peninsula", while "Maztica [...] was a large continent west of Faerûn." As such, while the statement in your header might be right, the rest of the answer does not reveal anything that supports that claim, especially since you apparently haven't checked all the official books yourself.

Comment: ...That said, one piece of evidence supporting your claim might be that [a DDB search for "Maztica"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=maztica) shows that there are almost no references to Maztica in any official D&D books, and what few mentions there are say nothing about the state of Maztica in the 1490s DR (effectively the "present day" for D&D 5e).

Comment: Sure, but they both disappeared to Abeir and don't have any official 149X lore that I know of. But if you know more... please, feel free to post an answer yourself... I'd be very curious to read that.

Comment: As an added point, Lantan isn't mentioned much in W:DH. One NPC has forged an alliance with Lantan, and acquired a vehicle from them a year ago, but nothing is really mentioned about the current state of Lantan. Also, the [*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* mentions only this about Lantan since its return](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#Lantan): "Some ships claiming to be from returned Lantan have appeared in ports along the Sword Coast, but from what I hear, the Lantanese who emerge from them are guarded and say little about their homeland."

Comment: ToA mentions this about [a jewel once taken from Maztica](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/tomb-of-the-nine-gods#LostTreasures): "Tabaxi thieves might try to steal the jewel and bear it safely back to Maztica".

Comment: And [a sidebar in *Volo's Guide to Monsters* about tabaxi in the Forgotten Realms](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/character-races#TabaxiPersonality) says: "In the Forgotten Realms, tabaxi hail from Maztica, a realm located far across the ocean west of the Sword Coast. The tabaxi of Maztica are known for their isolation, and until recently they never ventured from their homeland. The tabaxi say little of why that has changed, though rumors persist of strange happenings in that distant land."

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing official about the existence of Maztica in 5th edition lore. A fan of the setting has written a full 5e conversion of the setting and its North America-flavored neighbor Anchorome on the DM's Guild website, but those are fanmade and not official.